# SwiftUI List selection value always nil

Tags: list, swiftui, selection

I'm a beginner, researched this problem, found it addressed but the answers are not applicable to my program. Trying to adapt them leads to more unresolvable issues.
I've distilled my code below to its bare essentials.

How do I get a List selection value to write into my Textfield, tf1 when the selection value is always nil?

Is there a fix, a work around, or another approach applicable to my objective?

```
import SwiftUI

var d1:[String:[String]] = [
    "energy":["heat","kinetic","light"],
    "matter":["gas","liquid","solid"],
    "space":["1dim","2dim","3dim"],]

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var cpo = Array(d1.keys).sorted()
    @State var tf1: String = "matter"
    @State  var selection: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("tf1", text: $tf1)
            List(cpo, id: \.self, selection: $selection) {
                i in Text(i)
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                tf1 = selection!
            }
        } //VS
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but the `Array` conversion is redundnant. Sorting the *subarray* returns a (new) Array.

Comment: Vadian: the dictionary keys, are then presented in the list in alphabetical order. Perhaps I misunderstood your comment?

Comment: `d1.keys.sorted()` does the same as `Array(d1.keys).sorted()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong modifier. The `.onTapGesture` you applied to the List will fire as soon as you click on the list. It will prevent every selection from the `List` and will try to force unwrap your `selection` var. `selection` will be nil at that time causing the crash.

Better:

Use the `.onChange` modifier to act on changes of `selection`. If the new value is nil provide an appropriate alternative. I used an empty string here.

```
import SwiftUI

var d1:[String:[String]] = [
    "energy":["heat","kinetic","light"],
    "matter":["gas","liquid","solid"],
    "space":["1dim","2dim","3dim"],]

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var cpo = Array(d1.keys).sorted()
    @State var tf1: String = "matter"
    @State  var selection: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("tf1", text: $tf1)
            List(cpo, id: \.self, selection: $selection) {i in
                Text(i)
            }
            .onChange(of: selection) { newValue in
                tf1 = newValue ?? ""
            }
        } //VS
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you don't need to have a selection in the `List` - you can just change the value of `tf1` directly. But the `.onTapGesture` must be applied to the `Text`, not to the `List`.

Here's the code:

```
@State var cpo = Array(d1.keys).sorted()
@State var tf1: String = "matter"

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField("tf1", text: $tf1)
        List(cpo, id: \.self) { i in
            Text(i)
                .onTapGesture {
                    tf1 = i
                }
        }
    } //VS
}
```